# How to make the output "pretty" using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to format output that comes out from Django Rest Framework? What I'm looking for is a Django/DRF equivalent to PHP JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

Currently, the output looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"username":"bartalamej","city":"Ostrava","photo":"uploads/avatars/a84232eff3aa407db95ff792aec77414.jpg"}
```

But I'd like it to look like this:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "username":"bartalamej",
  "city":"Ostrava",
  "photo":"uploads/avatars/a84232eff3aa407db95ff792aec77414.jpg"
}
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you want to print it inside your code?

Comment: I want to see the formatted output when I open the URL in my browser

Comment: You can use any json-formatter pluggins for that in browser.

Comment: I don't want to use plugin for browser - this will be a public API so I want server to render it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the view's `get_renderer_context` and set an indent:

```
def get_renderer_context(self):
    context = super().get_renderer_context()
    context['indent'] = 4
    return context
```

This will add an indent to the `json.dumps` call.

Alternatively, you can also leave that up to your client and add the indent within the `Accept` header as explained [in the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#jsonrenderer)

Comment: where should I put it to make it globally?

Comment: You could use a base class that overrides the method and derive your views from it.

Answer (score 0):

The [BrowseableAPIRenderer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#browsableapirenderer) formats JSON nicely for browsing. More information can be found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/).