# DRF Response returns string with formatting characters (newline and space) but is not actually formatting

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response

data = { "data":  [
            {"example":"a","id": 1},
            {"example":"b","id": 2},
            {"example":"c","id": 3},
            ], 
        "numItem": 3
       }
```

```
# case 1
return JsonResponse(data, json_dumps_params={"indent":4})
```

Returns this
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiryR.png)]

```
# case 2
return Response(json.dumps(data, indent=4), content_type='application/json')
```

Returns this
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBKKm.png)]
And

```
# case 3
json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)  
return Response(json.loads(json_data), content_type='application/json')
```

Returns this
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzeyw.png)]

I see that `Response` is returning a string. Meaning `json.dumps(data, indent=4)` actually returns a string and I am just passing the stringed JSON with `\n` and `space` (formatting).

But why does the formatting work properly with `JsonResponse`?

***How could I make `Response` also returns formatted JSON and displayed correctly?***

And, why is the JSON string passed not being displayed with the actual newline?

Comment: Could you provide the classes' imports to show up where these came from? It would be helpful if you also provide a description on top of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586385/how-to-make-the-output-pretty-using-django-rest-framework) you just need to override `get_renderer_context`
to something like this:

```
def get_renderer_context(self):
    context = super().get_renderer_context()
    context['indent'] = 4
    return context
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This did fix the problem but it kinda defeats my intention of using `Response` because it would look cleaner. Tho I could create a class Mixin that override `get_renderer_context`, but that would just add more code. I will just stick with `JsonResponse`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**To return the data in a JSON format**

As your data is already in a Python dictionary type, you just need to pass this data without any formatting or transformation to the `Response` class.

`return Response(data)`

**Misunderstanding**

Your case 1 and case 3 are returning the same JSON content. Seems these are different because your request manager preview doesn't indent the case 3 response. In both classes, you don't need any transformation to return the requested data.

Implement these views below, and try these on Postman to see how it returns exactly the same thing.

```py
data = {"data": [
    {"example": "a", "id": 1},
    {"example": "b", "id": 2},
    {"example": "c", "id": 3},
],
    "numItem": 3
}


class ResponseOnlyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(data)


class ResponseLoadDataView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
        return Response(json.loads(json_data), content_type='application/json')


@csrf_exempt
def json_response_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(data)

@csrf_exempt
def json_response_indent_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(data, json_dumps_params={"indent":4})
```

The URLs

```py
...
    path("stack1/", ResponseOnlyView.as_view(), name="DRF view"),
    path("stack2/", ResponseLoadDataView.as_view(), name="DRF over"),

    path("stack3/", json_response_view, name="Django JSON view"),
    path("stack4/", json_response_indent_view, name="Django JSON view over"),
```

Comment: Hi Cladius, this does not really answer my question. Here, endpoint stack1,2,3 will return the same JSON that is without formatting, like case 3. However, stack 4 will return the desired results. JSON with formatting, like case 1.  
But I would still have to use `JsonResponse`. I want to use `Response` so it works with the browser api interface from DRF. I am still trying to figure out how to have `Response` return a indented JSON like case 3.